# Add to list if not already in list, change elements in list (PROLOG)

Tags: list, prolog, append

I am new to Prolog and I am trying to write a function that checks to see if a given key is in a list; if it is, it will increment the value in the list, otherwise it will append to the end of the list. Here is my code so far.

```
placeKey( Key, []       , List2 ) :- append(Key,[], List2).  %base case: append to empty list
placeKey( Key, [K|Rest] , List2 ) :-  %If front entry isnt the one we want then continue on the rest
  Key \= K ,
  put( Key ,Rest,List2).
placeKey(Key,[Key|Rest], List2):- %how to update item value?
```

However, this just returns a single list when the item isnt in the given list, and I don't even know how to approach the problem of actually changing the item in the list. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would use pattern matching instead of 'commands' to solve the task:

```
placeKey(Key, [], [Key]).
placeKey(Key, [K|Rest], [K|List2]) :- Key \= K, placeKey(Key, Rest, List2).
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to include a "key value". One is to use a key-value pair with the hyphen functor. I'll <strike>steal</strike> borrow liberally from CapelliC's excellent answer to the base question and add in the key tabulation logic:

```
% Key not present, then it goes in with count 1
place_key(Key, [], [Key-1]).

% Key is at the head, then it's included in the new list with incremented count
% and the rest of the list is unchanged
place_key(Key, [Key-V|Rest], [Key-V1|Rest]) :-
    V1 is V+1.

% Current head is not the key, so it's just copied over and the rest
% of the list is processed
place_key(Key, [K-V|Rest], [K-V|List2]) :-
    Key \= K,
    place_key(Key, Rest, List2).
```

So, for example:

```
| ?- place_key(x, [], L).

L = [x-1] ? ;

no
| ?- place_key(x, [x-2,y-3,z-1], L).

L = [x-3,y-3,z-1] ? ;

no
| ?- place_key(w,[x-2,y-3,z-1], L).

L = [x-2,y-3,z-1,w-1] ? ;

no
```

One nice aspect of the key-value format is that ISO Prolog defines a predicate, `keysort/2` that recognizes it.

```
| ?- place_key(q,[x-2,y-3,z-1], L), keysort(L, LX).

L = [x-2,y-3,z-1,q-1]
LX = [q-1,x-2,y-3,z-1] ? ;  % List sorted by key

no
| ?-
```

You can also do this using sublists of two elements (`[Key,Value]`) which might be the original intention, although it wasn't clear. The above logic is easily adapted to this format, if desired. (Everywhere you have `K-V` pattern, replace it with `[K,V]`.) And if you do a list sort on such a list, it will still sort by key:

```
| ?- sort([[c,1],[x,4],[d,5],[a,6],[m,2]], L).

L = [[a,6],[c,1],[d,5],[m,2],[x,4]]

yes
| ?-
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

This uses a tuple of the form `Key/Count` to represent each list item.

```
add_or_increment( Dict , K , Updated ) :-     % to add or increment a tuple in a dictionary-like list
  nonvar(K) ,                                 % - the key must be bound.
  append( Prefix , [K/N|Suffix] , Dict ) ,    % - use the key to find the tuple in the list.
  ! ,                                         % - eliminate the choice point.
  M is N+1 ,                                  % - increment the count
  append( Prefix , [K/M|Suffix] , Updated )   % - construct the updated list
  .                                           % - Easy!
add_or_increment( Dict , K , [K/1|Dict] ) :-  % otherwise, just prepend the key to the source list to create the updated list
  nonvar(K)                                   % - assuming, of course, that the key is bound.
  .                                           % - Even easier!
```